# How To Access Google Analytics Api Data Without Login

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to figure out a way to display data collected from Google Analytics on my web site to all users.Is there any way data can be shown to all users without login?

I'm using Google analytics Api v4 and working in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can do this without JavaScript by creating a data studio report
  and select the "embed" option (which gives an embeddable iframe that
  can be viewed without permissions).
- Another way would be to use a Google spreadsheet with some Apps
  script to retrieve the data and then publish it as a web app with a
  function that serves as end point to return formatted data (e.g. if
  you want a JSON feed for consumption in another app). You can use a
  time based trigger to refresh the data hourly (or another reasonable 
  interval).
- You can use the [Google Analytics Super Proxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) (some assembly
  required).
- You can use a dashboard service that provides embeddable charts.

Comment: Is Google Analytics Super Proxy can be used with client-side javascript?

Comment: No, not really. Super Proxy runs on the Google App engine.

Comment: Google Analytics Super Proxy worked for me.Thanks for your answer